# WatchKit present a SKScene from another unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value

Tags: sprite-kit, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-3

I want to present a SpriteKit scene from another SKScene in my WatchKit app.
Here is my code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
var scene2: Scene2!
@IBOutlet var skInterface: WKInterfaceSKScene!
override func sceneDidLoad() {
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
 ....
 changeScene()

 }
func changeScene() {
if let scene = Scene2(fileNamed: "Scene2") {

        scene2 = scene


        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill


        self.skInterface.presentScene(scene)


        self.skInterface.preferredFramesPerSecond = 30
    }
```

}
But when i try to present other scene i get this error:

```
   "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Your skInterface is what is nil

Comment: ok that's clear...so how i can load a SKscene from my GameScene?

Comment: Instead of skInterface being an IBOutlet, make it a regular variable, and in your view controller, when you initially present the scene,  assign the variable afterwards.

Comment: i made this for the GameScene...declared in InterfaceController and loaded from it. But now i must load this new scene from the GameScene itself.